# How can I store lists of lists properly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, graph-theory

I have a really huge dataframe that i'm using to construct a graph.
In doing so, I'am storing my nodes first and second degrees of connections as lists of lists.

Imagine the following graph:

```
    1 -> 2 and 2 -> 3 and 2 -> 4 and
    1 -> 5 and 5 -> 6
```

can be thus represented by:

```
    import pandas as pd
    nodes = pd.DataFrame(
                    [
                    [1,[2, 5], [[3, 4], [6, 7]]],
                    [2, [3, 4], [[], []]],
                    [5, [6], [[]]]
                    ], columns = ['Zero', 'First', 'Second']
                )

|0  |Zero   |First | Second|
|:--|:--|:-----|:-----------------|
|0  |1  |[2, 5]|[[3, 4], [6, 7]]|
|1  |2  |[3, 4]|[[], []]|
|2  |5  |[6]|[[]]|
```

Until now everything is fine, but as I said, this dataframe is huge and storing it as pickle is too memory intensive because I can have hugely insane lists of lists.

My question is: how can i store this data in a more memory-effective way? Should I drop empty lists and replace them with `np.nan's`? Exporting to csv and reading the data with `eval()` it's not satisfactory either.

Thank you!

Comment: I would store your graph as a matrix and get your neighbors on the fly as needed.

Comment: Why don't you just store edge list? Something akin to what [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html#:~:text=By%20definition%2C%20a%20Graph%20is%20a%20collection%20of,object%2C%20another%20Graph%2C%20a%20customized%20node%20object%2C%20etc.) uses for [`from_pandas_edgelist`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html?highlight=from_pandas)?

Comment: @QuangHoang for the computations that I need to do, I need to kown  by wich nodes the conections are coming form, threfore I'm sotring the nodes in lists of lists so I kwon from the example, what came from 2 and 5 exactly

Comment: can you not compute it on-the-fly with [`nx.dag.descendants`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.descendants.html)? Or you could just query `df.loc[df['zero'].eq(2), 'First']`?

Comment: @kpie I understand the ideia, but I have more than 8 million unique nodes and a matrix would be too costly

Comment: @QuangHoang I thought about that, but i'm not sure how networkx do this computations, I'm afraid that the object would be too heavy... do you kown about this? I searched but didn't find anything in the docs

Comment: @QuangHoang assume that I need to store the path

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have enough knowledge about large graph to answer your question. Yet, I imagine you store (directed) edge list is more efficient than what you did there. For example `2 -> [3, 4]` is stored twice in your data structure. You need to make a trade-off between pre-calculate information (2nd deg nodes) vs. storage based on your use case.

Comment: Are there situations where you're storing duplicate data? for instance, 0,1,2 -> 3,4,5 and all of 3, 4, 5 go to 6, 7, 8? Because if I'm understanding correctly, then your dataframe's size would grow as n^2, like the first three rows would be `[0, [1,2,3], [[4,5,6],[4,5,6],[4,5,6]]]`, so you're storing duplicate data

Comment: "I have a really huge dataframe that i'm using to construct a graph. In doing so, I'am storing my nodes first and second degrees of connections as lists of lists." Why are you using a dataframe for this? That doesn't make any sense. Dataframes are for working with panel-like data, ideally numeric data. You want to store an object graph.

Comment: As noted, there are already graph libraries out there, and likely, you should just use one of those, ideally one backed by C/C++ code instead of native Python data structures, which will be memory intensive

Comment: Dataframes really shine when they use a defined set of columns and a defined set of edges. Storing an adjacency list is not what they're good at, particularly not a 2-step adjacency list. If you're using dataframes, the natural graph representations they'd be good at is storing are adjacency matrixes (N columns, N rows, you'd want to use [sparse dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html)) and edge lists (2 columns, edge_source, edge_destination. To query, you do .where() calls and joins)

Comment: Thank you guys for all the raised considerations, I though having pre-calculate information (as pointed by @QuangHoang) even if duplicated, would make my algorith faster, and it made, but its too heavy... I will consider your suggestions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.